# Best practice Manim animations

Tags: python, animation, package, manim

I would like to ask for best practice tips to create my own animation package. I have been using a quite suboptimal set of files like https://github.com/PanoPepino/4K_Liverpool_2022/tree/main/Code%20for%20the%20Talk to craft presentations like https://panopepino.github.io/4K_Copenhague_2022/.

I have though of a structure like this:

```
.
├── figures
├── objects
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── vmobject_1.py
│   └── vmobject_2.py
├── script_slides.py
└── text
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── dialogue.py
    └── refs.py
```

Where each vmobject_i.py will contain a specific vgroup to animate. Is this an optimal/profesional way to craft animations in Manim? What can I do to improve it?

Other thing I was wondering is if I could also asign specific animations to each vmobject, like:

```py
class Bubble(VMObject):
  def construct(self):
      ... my_vgroup ...

  def expand(self):
      return self.play(my_vgroup.animate.scale(2))
```

So in script_slides.py, I just have to call the bubble's function *expand* instead of typing down self.play(...). Is this possible? If so, Can you give me a hint on how to do it? Is there anything even more optimal for a process like this that I am not aware of?

Thank you in advance for your help.

I have so far tried the previous structure and it seems to work. I cannot yet understand how to give specific animation definitions to each object, such that they perform the set of desired animations with a single command. Any tips on this?